# Ifelse NULL: obtaining numeric instead of string values

Tags: r, if-statement, na, dplyr

This seems to be very easy to do but I couldn't find an answer. I have two variables in my dataframe regarding Area names. I want to create a final Area variable using this two variables. If Area2 is missing then just use Area1 values but if Area2 is not missing the use Area2 values.

```
Area    Area2  Goal
ABC            ABC
ABC            ABC
AAA     AAA    AAA
AA-A    AAA    AAA
A AA    AAA    AAA

data <- data.frame(Area1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "AAA", "AA-A", "A AA"),
                   Area2 =c("", "", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA"))
```

My tried is below but I am obtaining numeric values for my final variable instead of string values (even using the as.factor option).

```
data$AreaFinal <- ifelse(is.na(data$Area2), data$Area1, data$Area2)
data$AreaFinal <- ifelse(is.na(data$Area2), as.factor(data$Area1), data$Area2)
```

Does this code look ok? In my real data Area1 is a factor and Area 2 is a character.

Thank you in advance! 
Marvin

Comment: I think you need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` i the `data.frame` call a  BTW, you don't have `NA `elements.  It is `""` .  the condition should be `ifelse(data$Area2 == "", data$Area1, data$Area2)#
[1] "ABC" "ABC" "AAA" "AAA" "AAA"`

Comment: To do the first part "stringsAsFactors = FALSE i the data.frame". I did  data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE). But when I run ifelse(data$Area2 == "", data$Area1, data$Area2) I am getting the same results (numbers).

Comment: The second `ifelse` does **not** look ok. If the factors levels (of `Area1` and `Area2`) are not the same a warning will be thrown.

Comment: Hi Rui Thanks for taking the time. I tried many things but can't still get it. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert my Area1 variable from factor to character `data$area1<- as.character(data$area1)` . Then `data$areafinal<- with(data, ifelse(is.na(area), area1, area2))`